# `regex_match` returns both 'not found' and `match_results`

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

In the following code (gcc 10.2.1), the call to `regex_match` returns 'no match', which I believe is correct.

`sm.size()` returns `0`, but when iterating from `sm.begin()` to `end()`, it finds 3 occurrences (all empty strings).

If this is correct, what do these 3 finds mean ?

But since `size()==0`, shouldn't `begin() == end()` ?

Edit: Based on comments, I added the `ready` flag to the output

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <assert.h>

int main()
{
    std::string input("4321");
    std::regex rg("^([0-9])");
    std::smatch sm;

    bool found = std::regex_match(input, sm, rg);

    assert(!sm.size() == sm.empty());

     std::cout << "ready: " << sm.ready() << ", found: " <<
          found << ", size: " << sm.size() << std::endl;


    for (auto it = sm.begin(); it != sm.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << "iterate '" << *it << "'\n";
    }
}
```

output:

```
ready: 1, found: 0, size: 0
iterate ''
iterate ''
iterate ''
```

Comment: I've deleted my answer as I had completely misread the question in an attempt to answer fast. However, now that I read it carefully, probably it's worth a bug report, because it's unlikely that it is expected that the following fails: `assert(sm.size() == (unsigned long)std::distance(sm.begin(), sm.end()));`.

Comment: (For whatever range/iterable.)

Comment: @Enlico The standard has this to say: "**[re.alg.match]/3** *Postconditions:* `m.ready() == true` in all cases. If the function returns `false`, then the effect on parameter `m` is unspecified except that `m.size()` returns `0` and `m.empty()` returns `true`." So arguably `m.begin()` after an unsuccessful match exhibits unspecified behavior.

Comment: @Enlico On the other hand, there's "**[re.results]/2** The class template `match_results` satisfies the requirements of an allocator-aware container ...", and one of the container requirements (per **[container.requirements.general]** Table 83) is that `a.size()` return `distance(a.begin(), a.end())` for a container `a`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, your first comment is something that I though about, but it's just weird that `m.size()` is specified and `std::distance(m.begin(), m.end())` is not. In your second comment... Wait, am I confused or is the standard confused?

Comment: It looks like an issue in the standard library implementation, which can be reproduced in Clang as well. If one adds `-stdlib=libc++` command-line option to switch to Clang libc++ then the output becomes expected: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/cq7EWsKPb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In GCC's implementation of `match_results` the prefix, suffix, and unmatched string are stored at the end of the sequence managed by the `match_results` object (which is implemented as a private `std::vector` base class). Those extra elements should not be visible when iterating from `begin()` to `end()`, but the `end()` function is returning the wrong position. It's returning an iterator to the end of the vector, after the three extra elements. It should be returning an iterator just before those, which would be equal to `begin()`.

This is a bug, obviously. I'll fix it.

The fix is:

```
       const_iterator
       end() const noexcept
-      { return _Base_type::end() - (empty() ? 0 : 3); }
+      { return _Base_type::end() - (_Base_type::empty() ? 0 : 3); }
```